# Php - Template lite

Tags: php, templates, template-lite

I really searched but found nothing.

I'm new at template lite. I add my project template_lite library and I have two files.

test.php is:

```
require("../src/class.template.php");
$tpl = new Template_Lite;
$tpl->compile_dir = "compiled/";
$tpl->compile_dir = "templates/";
$tpl->assign("foo","bar");
```

and i have simple html to see my code

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Document Title</title>
</head>
<body>
{$foo}
</body>
</html>
```

it prints "{$foo}" not bar why :S

Comment: did you place the html inside a .tpl page in the proper directory?

Comment: Did you define $foo anywhere?

Comment: how can place the html inside a .tpl :S is .tpl essential ?

Comment: do i have to copy test.html to templates directory with tpl file ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be missing the call to `display()`. A [typical template sample](http://templatelite.sourceforge.net/docs/getting.started.html) needs the following

```
// test.php
require("../src/class.template.php");
$tpl = new Template_Lite;
$tpl->compile_dir = "compiled/";
$tpl->compile_dir = "templates/";
$tpl->assign("foo","bar");

$tpl->display("test.tpl");
```

and the template in `templates/test.tpl`

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Document Title</title>
</head>
<body>
{* this is a comment *}
{ $foo }
</body>
</html>
```

The URL you request in your browser would be `test.php`

Comment: my mistake is  calling test.html instead of test.php thank you